# Swiper.js and Vue transition group

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I would like to use the `transition-group` tag with the `swiper-slide` tag (from swiper.js).

Premise:
This code

```
 <swiper
    :slidesPerView="'auto'"
    :space-between="20"
 >
    <swiper-slide
        v-for="item of list"
        :key="item.id"
    >
        <!-- slide content -->
    </swiper-slide>
 </swiper>
```

Will be rendered like this

```
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I try to add a `transition-group` tag

```
<swiper
    :slidesPerView="'auto'"
    :space-between="20"
>
    <transition-group name="animation">
        <swiper-slide
            v-for="item of list"
            :key="item.id"
        >
            <!-- slide content -->
        </swiper-slide>
    </transition-group>
 </swiper>
```

This is the result:

```
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
</div>
```

What can I do?